# Is there a way to restart tomcat using paramiko?

Tags: python, tomcat, paramiko

when I try to run the following code:

```
import paramiko
s = paramiko.SSHClient()

s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect(hostname="192.168.30.68", username="root", password="123456")
stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command("sh /Application/tomcat/bin/startup.sh")
print stdout.read()
s.close()
```

I get the following output:

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

The tomcat on the remote server is not started. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: You could wrap calling startup command in another script that sets the environment variables appropriately, and call script from `exec_command`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I resolve it by adding s.exec_command("source  /etc/profile") .